# Why does impugn = oppugn?

Tags: verbs

Their definitions look the same—[impugn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impugn?q=impugn) vs. [oppugn](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oppugn?q=oppugn)—yet they have different prefixes. Why don't they have opposite meanings? Would someone please explain this discrepancy?

Comment: Why would words having different prefixes meaning respectively ‘into, against’ and ‘against, towards’ be expected to have opposite meanings? _In-_ and _ob-_ have meanings that sometime overlap, at least partly, though actual word pairs like this one are uncommon due to the relative paucity of verbs in _ob-_ compared to ones in _in-_.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that OED has a total of **seven** different definitions under four headings for ***oppugn***, of which one is marked "rare", and all the rest "obsolete". But I certainly don't see why one would expect ***opposite*** meanings just because two words have different prefixes.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers I have noted that some people do become obsessed with symmetry on this site; an assumption that everything has its equal and opposite, and that words are subject to the laws of mathematics.

Comment: @WS2: How true. But such people are almost always non-native speakers. Presumably, desperately hoping for some sign that English *usage* might not be as complicated as it initially seems. Sadly for them, I suspect the truth is that it's actually far *more* complex than most ESL students think.

Comment: As to prefixes and expected opposites, why can _flammable_ and _inflammable_ have similar meanings? As a bonus, those words are actually _used_, in contrast to the ones in the question :P

Comment: For what it's worth, I have never seen "oppugn" before. The collision with impugn may be part of why it has fallen out of use.

Comment: This just came up on Anu Garg's daily word list. Here's a usage reference: “President Susilo Bambang Yudhoyono last week put the blame on the media, accusing media organizations of destroying the party’s image. Furthermore, he oppugned press credibility.”
Donny Syofyan; Blame Game and Political Suicide of Indonesian Elites; The Jakarta Post (Indonesia); Jul 25, 2011.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it is their Latin origin that is responsible for the the differen prefixes but similar meaning:

[Impugn](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Impugn&searchmode=none)(v.):[Impugn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Impugn)

> To attack as false or questionable; challenge in argument: impugn a political opponent's record.

Etymology

> "attack by argument," late 14c., from Old French impugner, from *Latin impugnare* "to assault, to attack," from assimilated form of in- "into, in, on, upon" (see in- (2)) + pugnare "to fight" (see pugnacious). Related: Impugned; impugning.

[Oppugn](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=oppugn&searchmode=none)n (v.) :[Oppugn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Oppugn)

> To oppose, contradict, or call into question.

Etymology

> mid-15c., *from Latin oppugnare* "to fight against, attack, assail," from ob- "toward, against" (see ob-) + pugnare "to fight" (see pugnacious). Related: Oppugned; oppugning.

Comment: Ultimately, the prefixes go back to Proto-Indo-European _*en_ meaning "in", and _*epi_ meaning "near" or "against". The two are clearly related.

Answer (score -1):

See also "A Word A Day", June 24, 2015, http://wordsmith.org/words/oppugn.html, where the editor cites a usage of "oppugn" in a Jakarta, Indonesia, newspaper from July, 2011.  (This reinforces the notion that "oppugn" is used by nonnative English speakers.)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain the meat of the article you are referencing, rather than relying on the reference alone.